# Sql phone number constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, constants

Constraint for Phone Number. if it is starting with 03 then it must be 11 digits long, but if the digits are 10 then the second digit must not be 3. my code is not working correctly help please.

```
c_Phone varchar(11) unique c_Phone check(c_Phone not like '%[^0-9]%'and 
((c_Phone like '03%' and len(c_Phone)=11) or 
(c_Phone like '0^3%' and len(c_Phone)=10))))
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? Read [How to create a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and remove the erroneous DB tag (pick mysql or sql server)

Comment: As much as you might wish, phone numbers do not conform to any reasonable expectations. This is a bad idea.

Comment: i edited the post, please see again

Comment: Does this work for you? (c_Phone like '03%' and len(c_Phone)=11)  OR
(c_Phone NOT like '[0-9]3%' and len(c_Phone)=10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alter table dbo.Test
add constraint UQ_Phone unique (c_Phone)


alter table dbo.Test
add constraint CC_Phone  check
(
    c_Phone not like '%[^0-9]%'and 
    ((c_Phone like '03%' and len(c_Phone) = 11) or 
    (c_Phone not like '_3%' and len(c_Phone) = 10))
)
```